# why is javax.servlet not available for import?

Tags: java, servlets

I have java sdk 1.7. I've always used django/python for web development, this will be the first time I use java.

When I tried:

```
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

servlet is not found? How do I properly install this servlet jar?

EDIT:

I am developing some small stuff for google app engine using java.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"javax.servlet.*" and friends come with whatever servlet container you're using.  Tomcat uses j2ee.jar or servlet.jar (IIRC), WebSphere uses a different .jar, etc.

You're using  Google App Engine.

That means you need to use the Google .jar files.

Here's the documentation:

> https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime
>
> App Engine knows to use the Java runtime environment for your
>   application when you use the AppCfg tool from the Java SDK to upload
>   the app.
>
> There is only one version of the App Engine Java API. This API is
>   represented by the appengine-api-*.jar included with the SDK (where *
>   represents the version of the API and the SDK). You select the version
>   of the API your application uses by including this JAR in the
>   application's WEB-INF/lib/ directory. If a new version of the Java
>   runtime environment is released that introduces changes that are not
>   compatible with existing apps, that environment will have a new
>   version number. Your application will continue to use the previous
>   version until you replace the JAR with the new version (from a newer
>   SDK) and re-upload the app.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't come with standard JDK, you need to add the servlet-api.jar in your classpath

Comment: can you please give me some instructions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

it doesnt come with disttribution of core J2Se distibution ..because this API depends on which server(tomcat, jetty) you are using . so it comes with the server   . If you are using tomcat its there in tomcat lib directry witth name of servler-api.jar . add it to your classpath

Answer (score 1):

If your IDE is Intellij you'll have to get the Ultimate version.

Below are the features of [Intellij IDEA ultimate edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/).

- Full-featured IDE for JVM-based and polyglot development
- Java EE, Spring/Hibernate and other technologies support
- Deployment and debugging with most application servers
- Duplicate code search, dependency structure matrix, etc.

Then you can easily start a Intellij J2EE project which will include all the necessary jars in the classpath. 
Hope this helps.